# How to get the row with max timestamp in postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql, timestamp, max

I need to get a row of information with max timestamp in postgresql. Below is a demo for this question:

```
drop table Mytable cascade
create table MyTable (usr char(1), event_dt timestamp without time zone);
insert into mytable values ('A','01-JAN-2009 11:10:11');
insert into mytable values ('A','02-JAN-2009 11:10:22');
insert into mytable values ('B','02-JAN-2009 01:01:59' );
insert into mytable values ('C', '31-DEC-2008 02:02:02');
insert into mytable values ('D', '31-DEC-2008 03:03:03');
```

If I do

```
select max(event_dt) from (
select usr,event_dt from mytable where usr= 'A') as foo
```

It is sort of what I need but it only returns the event_dt 
"2009-01-02 11:10:22"

Where I want the usr as well sa event_dt from that row. How do I do it?

Comment: What do you want to do if there are several rows with the `max(event_dt)`?

Comment: I rolled back to your previous version. Please don't add another question, start a *new* one for that. You can find your text in the edit history if you need it. Also: many closely related questions. [Here's one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/sql-select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I would simply go for...

```
SELECT usr, event_dt FROM mytable ORDER BY event_dt DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: **Timing difference**? I conducted a timing test on roughly one billion rows of data on both the OP and Najzero's solutions. There's aproxemately a 25% performance gain to doing Najzero's solution as well. So not only does it look clean but it's way faster (perhaps for obvious reasons)